# How to upload a file to firebase storage with absolute path of it instead of using URI in android studio

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I don't wanna use a uri with user interaction I only need a file from an absolute path like "/storage/emulated/0/myapp/sample.jpg" is there any way to upload a file in that way please help

Note : I'm using java

Comment: See the Firebase documentation on [uploading from a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file). If you have trouble making that work, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks I think I should make a uri with the absolute path then pass it as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi my friend can fix this by only adding your fill path into the File Object, this way can obtain a valid URL, such as this example

```
var file = Uri.fromFile(File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"))
```

and set the fill to putFile Function such as this

```
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file)
```

can you review everything from [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file)